# Need polynomial time implementation for pycddlib polyhedra representation.

Tags: convex-optimization, computational-complexity, polyhedra, python

Request for reference

We are using the python library pycddlib as API working with polyhedra. Here is the link
https://pycddlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/polyhedron.html

We have set of linear equations and we want to get the polyhedra and do various mathematical operations with that. We are successful with the operations. But as the number of equations get large the library could not handle it. I guess the time complexity involved in the pycddlib is exponential. I saw in literature there polynomial time algorithm for Linear programming. So wondering if there is similar library doing the same function and methods?